# F5 Load balancer- http to https Site, Mixed content browser error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, load-balancing

We have configured F5 load balancer with https certificate and all this request till F5 are being in SSL. Load balancer does transition to http request in internal network.

I have SharePoint Site which has been hosted on iis port 80. Within network I can request it using http and can access without any problem.

But when I use https over internet I am receiving following error,

> Mixed-Content The page at ' https://url' was loaded over https but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest  'script .js' endpoint
>   'http://ur/". This request has been blocked; the content must be
>   served over HTTPS.

We are giving relative paths to all resources eg: `'_layout\script.js'` no protocol being hardcoded.

Our platform policies do not allow us to have https within internal network. All other applications are working with same topology but not SharePoint. Please help.

Here is snapshot of error

[[image: Error]

Comment: Do you see any errors at SharePoint side when this happens? Maybe you should talk to F5 support

Comment: No, there are no errors in SharePoint, its blocking by Browser. We can override it from browser setting but this is not the right way from user perspective. I checked with platform team, they have no clue.

Comment: This might be an AAM issue, but then you could see entries in ULS and Application log of Windows Server. Can you please double check? Or maybe describe how your AAM is configured.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it with setting internet url as https, but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set web application's AAM settings like these:

> Default zone:
>
> - Internal URL: https://FQDN, Public URL for Zone:    https://FQDN
> - Internal URL: http://SERVER, Public URL for Zone:    https://FQDN

Here, `FQDN` is external url for SharePoint, `SERVER` is internal. Might be the same.

Also one might want to take a look at [The final guide to Alternate Access Mappings](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/The-final-guide-to-551bd75b)

Comment: Thanks for your time for answer and link. I had tried this and observation is that it works only when https traffic is allowed from LB. We want to avoid that and would like to have http traffic only within internal network and no IIS binding with certificate is allowed.

Comment: Yes, I got it - you're doing SSL termination (when all HTTPS is done by LB). Maybe these helps: http://onpointwithsharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/02/configuring-sharepoint-alternate-access.html and http://wwolfe.blogspot.com/2011/01/quick-tip-using-f5-products-for-ssl.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's the term. Let me check it tomorrow on Test server. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Note that SSL Offloading is very insecure, especially when using OAuth2 tokens (SharePoint Apps, WA, WFM, etc). It won't be better to use SSL Bridging.

Comment: @AzizKabyshev, it did helped but partially, very inconsistent in response, it still gives error sometime and sometime it works, unreliable. So we finally decided to use SSL inside the network as well.

Comment: @TrevorSeward, I didn't get this properly, will you please elaborate more? or provide links which would help me to understand it better?

Comment: WAC, WFM, SharePoint Apps, etc. use OAuth. OAuth is insecure without transport security in place. When you use SSL Offloading, that connection between the LB and SharePoint goes over plain text HTTP. That connection can be intercepted, and OAuth tokens replayed by an attacker to gain the rights of the target user (as described by the OAuth token). Given most attackers come from inside a network, rather than outside, it is important to have end-to-end security, which SSL Offloading expressly does not allow for.

Comment: @ShankarGurav I think you made right decision. Nowadays it's recommended to have SSL/TLS everywhere